# Bootstrap 5 Style not working properly with Angular 16

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, bootstrap-5, angular-json

The problem is in my angular.json i declared my styles like this.

`"styles": [ { "input": "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "bundleName": "ltrCSS" }, { "input": "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css", "bundleName": "rtlCSS" }, "src/[FOLDER]/styles.css", "src/[FOLDER]/rtlcustomstyle.css" ],`

and when im building my site for prod it produces two extra styles but when im building it locally it does not have any error.
**Local Build**
[Local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZv0E.png)
**Prod Build**
[Prod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucbkm.png)

I have tried to mix and match codes and ranking of the styles but it still not works. As you can see below the css file it has a additional `<style>...</style>` the content of it is what exactly inside the bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 0):

I use bootstrap 5 in latest Angular version.
There is my steps:
1(Terminal). ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
2(angular.json => add to first style element). "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
3(restart terminal by typin ctrl + c then ng serve).

Comment: I already implemented this, as you can see on the code and screenshot i had provided